# Why do I have problems to fetch users name in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a Javascript, HTML and CSS proyect. What I want is to get the name of a user using its Id. I use fetch to do that but I am getting some problems.

```
function getUserName(userId) {
  let userTemp = window.API_HOST + '/users/' + userId;
  return fetch(userTemp, {
    headers: { authorization: localStorage.access_token },
  })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
      console.log('El nombre es: ' + response.name);
      return response.name;
    });
}
```

The problem here is that response.name is a promise object and not the actual name. I tried to use stringify but it did not work. Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**
I need to call that function in a place like this:

```
function showOffer(newOffer) {
  if (newOffer.user_id === JSON.parse(localStorage.current_user)._id) {
    const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    wrapper.className = 'wrap';
    const prodHolder = document.getElementById('demo').appendChild(wrapper);

    const offerBidderId = document.createElement('p');
    const offerBidderIdText = document.createTextNode(
      'Bidder id: ' + getUserName(newOffer.bidder_id),
    );
    console.log('New offer bidder id ' + newOffer.bidder_id);
    offerBidderId.appendChild(offerBidderIdText);
    wrapper.appendChild(offerBidderId);
    ....
}
```

Maybe here is the problem?

Comment: can you give an example of what `userId` might contain as a value?

Comment: If the response.name is type of promise as you said then you would have to use `.then` method to access its value

Comment: @Ahmad the userId is just a long integer

Comment: If it's a promise, you certainly should do something like : userId.then(function(someParameter) {
    console.log(someParameter);
});

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetch` returns always a `Promise`. So you have to handle it with `then` or `async/await`.

You can access it like this:

```
getUserName(1).then(name => {
   console.log('El nombre es: ' + name);
});
```

or inside an async function:

```
async function access() {
    const name = await getUserName(1);

    console.log('El nombre es: ' + name);
}
```

Nice article about async functions: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/async-functions

Comment: This was the answer that helped me the most